# Using FindMinimum of a function imported via DefineDLLFunction

Tags: mathematical-optimization, .netlink

Mathematica newbie here, just used it today for the first time.

So I've successfully "imported" a function from a dll I've built (in C++ with VS), using .NET/LINK and DefineDLLFunction and I've assigned it the name MyFunction. The function evaluates just fine when I call it directly (i.e. passing a double as an argument). But when I try to find a local minimum using say

```
FindMinimum[{MyFunction[x], 1 < x < 2}, {x, 1.5}]
```

I get

> ```
> NET::methodargs : Improper arguments supplied for method named...
> ```

Am I trying something that cannot be done, or am I doing it wrong? Can functions imported like that be used by `FindMinimum`?

Comment: Does it work if you put `FindMinimum[{f[x], 1 < x < 2}, {x, 1.5}]` where `f[x_?NumericQ]:=MyFunction[x]`?

Comment: Wow, you do know your stuff! Thank you so much for this and for taking the time to make my post more readable. Could you please explain what exactly the "?NumericQ"? specifier does? I had already done what you said (my function actually takes 16 arguments and I only want to change one, so I had mapped it to f[x_] := MyFunction[x, c1, c2, c3...], where c1, c2, c3 are the constant values for the other arguments), but without the "?NumericQ" magic part.

Comment: Take a look at this answer, it should explain it: [**26037**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/5478)

Comment: Again, thanks for the link with the pitfalls for new users, I'll be having a look at it I guess. But this was definitely an "obscure" solution for a newbie, so I don't feel that bad for not finding it myself with my 2-hour of googling (should I?!)

Comment: Another related question (please let me know if it's worth stating it as a separate question): So this worked and it takes about 5 secs for FindMinimum to find the minimum. An individual function evaluation takes about 70ms. But when I set EvaluationMonitor, it tells me there was only one evaluation. What can be the issue here? Obviously the function was evaluated many times.

Comment: @YianPap Did you use delayed (`:>`) or immediate (`->`) rule for `EvaluationMonitor`? If the latter, change it to the delayed rule.

Comment: Indeed I had used immediate as this comes up in auto-format by Mathematica. Changing to what you suggested fixed it. You guys are great, thanks a lot.